# Generate 3rd list from adding two different lists

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two lists

```
List A have 3 items
List A={[name: abc, desc: abcd, img: httpsURL1],
       [name: xyz, desc: wxyz, img: httpsURL2],
       [name: def, desc: sahdw, img: httpsURL3]}

List B has only one item and name argument is same in both
List B={[name: abc, progress: 0.75]},
```

Now I want to generate 3rd list like below:

```
List C = {[name: abc, desc: abcd, img: httpsURL1, progress:0.75],
       [name: xyz, desc: wxyz, img: httpsURL2, progress: 0],
       [name: def, desc: sahdw, img: httpsURL3, progress: 0]}
```

Is it possible in Dart?

Comment: possible of course, for example loop through the larger list and add the entries from the smaller list if key matches else add a default value

Comment: Can you please give me some code for default value,

Comment: I tried but it occurred index problem

Comment: @iDecode
i have 3 lists
List allData = HomeScreenState.listAllDataByDay;


  List progressData = HomeScreenState.progressDataListByDayAndDiseaseName;


  List cardAllData = List();

Comment: @ShahHaroon In your provided code, they are `Set` actually

Comment: Yes, you can do it but first its List _a = [] and not this List _a = {}
here look at the docs for List in Dart List in Dart
There are many function that can help you let me know if you need more help @ShahHaroon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did one assumption here, that the first list will always contain all elements. Otherwise this should be and example with the input you provided and also provide the output you expected.

Check this example in DartPad:
https://dartpad.dev/3cf607d4d0284702319e562099e19b1e

```
void main() {
  var aList = [
    new ClassA("abc", "abcd", "httpsURL1"),
    new ClassA("xyz", "wxyz", "httpsURL2"),
    new ClassA("def", "sahdw", "httpsURL3")
  ];

  var bList = [
    new ClassB("abc", 0.75),
  ];

  var result = aList
      .map((a) => bList.any((b) => b.name == a.name)
          ? new ClassC(a.name, a.desc, a.img,
              bList.firstWhere((b) => a.name == b.name).progress)
          : new ClassC(a.name, a.desc, a.img, 0))
      .toList();

  print(result);
}

class ClassA {
  String name;
  String desc;
  String img;

  ClassA(this.name, this.desc, this.img);
}

class ClassB {
  String name;
  double progress;

  ClassB(this.name, this.progress);
}

class ClassC {
  String name;
  String desc;
  String img;
  double progress;

  ClassC(this.name, this.desc, this.img, this.progress);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much buddy i was exactly looking for this, thanks :)